# Why doesn't the Stripe extension create financial records for fee amount?

Tags: stripe, accounting, financial-accounts, quickbooks

We are planning on changing our payment processor from PayPal to Stripe. When I exported the Accounting transactions to import into QuickBooks, I noticed that the Bank Fees aren't created for the Stripe transactions.

PayPal created two accounting transactions - one for the contribution and one for the bank fee.  Stripe doesn't seem to do that.  Stripe just creates the contribution transaction, even though I can see the fee when I look at the contribution.

Did I misconfigure Stripe or is this how Stripe is designed to work?  If so, how do others handle the financials for the fee charges?

Comment: Related Gitlab issue: https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/342